# Sens de "coqueluche du gouvernement"

Tags: sens

Bonsoir à tous et à toutes!

C'est quoi le sens de: **coqueluche du gouvernement** dans ce paragraphe?

> La découverte de 14 chefs d’accusation de fraude et de complot, la prise de conscience de
> l’effondrement d’une réputation. Passer de vice-première ministre, **coqueluche du
> gouvernement**, figure montante du parti de pouvoir, à accusée numéro 1 de la grande traque
> québécoise contre la corruption politique, il y a de quoi craquer. Et Normandeau nous raconte
> quand, comment et combien de temps elle craque. On la comprend. On souffre avec elle.

Merci d'avance!

Comment: B.− Au fig. Objet d'un engouement contagieux dans un groupe social donné. Synon. favori, idole; cf. une personne dont on est coiffé. https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coqueluche

Comment: Comment on the citation by Lambie: "Engouement contagieux" yes but in the background there is an idea that it is a temporary status, not an idol forever. Besides, the expression "Une personne dont on est coiffé" is not at all usual french !!

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker Je citait le dico. Rien de plus. Le même dico dit: Être coiffé de qqn, se coiffer de qqn.Avoir une attirance pour cette personne; s'engouer de. Se coiffer d'une servante. Se coiffer d'une drôlesse (G. Sand, François le Champi,1850, p. 30): https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coiff%C3%A9 Pourquoi critiquer la personne qui cite un dico? Les dicos sont bourrés de choses qui ne se disent plus.

Comment: @Lambi No critic for you but for the dictionnary which should have said "rare/inusité"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Être la coqueluche*** est une expression qui signifie *être au centre de l'attention, des discussions*, *susciter un grand enthousiasme, un grand engouement*. C'est un état qui, comme une mode, ne dure en général pas très longtemps.

*Être la coqueluche du gouvernement* peut avoir un sens plus ou moins large : être porté(e) aux nues par les autres membres du gouvernement ou être un membre du gouvernement porté aux nues pas la population en général.

Références: [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coqueluche) [Expressio](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/etre-la-coqueluche-de-quelqu-un)

<sub>Note: Le TLFi fait un rapprochement avec une expression du XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, *personne dont on est coiffé* (voir [coiffer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coiffer) **B.- 2.**: *se coiffer de quelqu'un*), mais elle est totalement oubliée aujourd'hui.</sub>